# Permission Denial when copy file from android gallery with ngCordova

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm using the ionicframework with the ngCordova [FileTransfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) plugin to copy an image from android gallery.

I'm try the following

```
$scope.getImage = function()
        {
            var options = {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: false
            };

            $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(
                function(fileUri)
                {
                    console.log(fileUri);
                    $cordovaFileTransfer.download(fileUri, cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'my-image.jpg', {}, true).then(
                        function(fileEntry)
                        {
                            $scope.images.imageUri = fileEntry.nativeURL;
                        },
                        function (error)
                        {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    );
                },
                function(error)
                {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        }
```

In the code above, errocallback is call and console show the error message:

"Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%253A19753 from pid=3933, uid=10194 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$cordovaFileTransfer` is not designed for copy/move a file. It is used for download and upload features.

You have to use `$cordovaFile` with method `copyFile(path, file, newPath, newFile)` instead.

Before using `$cordovaFile` you have to install its plugin with this command: `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file`

More information at [ngCordova - $cordovaFile](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/)

Hope it'll help!